# RecyclerView only populate data in debug mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-android

Having a strange issue when initializing RecyclerView. When I debug all of the content is populated correctly, and shows up in the list. When I run the app, getItemCount() remains 0.

I know that data is initialized because it's logged. But it looks like code isn't running in the correct order. Size is logged before the data is returned from Contentful.

Log when running without debugging:

```
10-27 13:15:01.436 21978-21978/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-27 13:15:01.436 21978-21978/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
10-27 13:15:01.449 21978-21983/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-27 13:15:01.449 21978-21983/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
10-27 13:15:01.550 21978-21978/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.x.x-1/lib/x86
10-27 13:15:01.560 21978-21978/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-27 13:15:01.664 21978-21978/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-27 13:15:01.738 21978-21978/? I/com.x.x.VideoListViewActivity: Size: 0
10-27 13:15:01.790 21978-21996/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-27 13:15:01.790 21978-21996/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
10-27 13:15:01.790 21978-21996/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-27 13:15:01.791 21978-21996/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
10-27 13:15:01.961 21978-21995/? I/com.x.x.Videos$1: Contentful:Test
10-27 13:15:01.961 21978-21995/? I/com.x.x.Videos$1: Contentful:Test 1
```

Log when running with debug:

```
10-27 13:15:42.116 22660-22660/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-27 13:15:42.117 22660-22660/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
10-27 13:15:42.130 22660-22667/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-27 13:15:42.130 22660-22667/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-27 13:15:42.130 22660-22667/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
10-27 13:15:42.149 22660-22660/? W/ActivityThread: Application com.httpk9fitclub.k9fitclub is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-27 13:15:42.149 22660-22660/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk

                                               [ 10-27 13:15:42.158  1612: 1635 D/         ]
                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x87c7f7c0, tid 1635
10-27 13:15:44.138 22660-22667/com.x.xI/art: Debugger is active
10-27 13:15:44.153 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: Debugger has connected
10-27 13:15:44.154 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-27 13:15:44.355 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-27 13:15:44.555 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-27 13:15:44.756 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-27 13:15:44.957 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-27 13:15:45.158 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-27 13:15:45.359 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-27 13:15:45.559 22660-22660/com.x.xI/System.out: debugger has settled (1403)
10-27 13:15:45.621 22660-22660/com.x.xW/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.x.x-1/lib/x86
10-27 13:15:45.628 22660-22660/com.x.xI/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-27 13:15:45.633 22660-22667/com.x.xI/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
10-27 13:15:45.783 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=16KB
10-27 13:15:45.784 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=13KB
10-27 13:15:45.784 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
10-27 13:15:45.824 22660-22660/com.x.xD/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-27 13:15:45.892 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=39KB
10-27 13:15:45.893 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: After code cache collection, code=58KB, data=38KB
10-27 13:15:45.893 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
10-27 13:15:46.320 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=81KB
10-27 13:15:46.321 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
10-27 13:15:46.321 22660-22663/com.x.xI/art: After code cache collection, code=95KB, data=57KB
10-27 13:15:46.341 22660-22731/com.x.xI/com.x.x.Videos$1: Contentful:Test
10-27 13:15:46.341 22660-22731/com.x.xI/com.x.x.Videos$1: Contentful:Test 1
10-27 13:15:46.341 22660-22731/com.x.xI/com.x.x.Videos$1: Contentful:Maggie Test
10-27 13:15:46.341 22660-22731/com.x.xI/com.x.x.Videos$1: Contentful:K9 Fit club Test
10-27 13:15:48.344 22660-22660/com.x.xI/com.x.x.VideoListViewActivity: Size: 4
10-27 13:15:48.431 22660-22769/com.x.xI/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-27 13:15:48.431 22660-22769/com.x.xD/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
10-27 13:15:48.431 22660-22769/com.x.xW/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-27 13:15:48.431 22660-22769/com.x.xD/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
```

VideoListViewActivity.java

```
public class VideoListViewActivity extends Activity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.video_list_activity);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        initializeAdapter();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        VideoListAdapter adapter = new VideoListAdapter(this, new Videos());
        Log.i("size", "" + adapter.getItemCount());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Videos.java

```
public class Videos {
private static final String CDA_TOKEN = "x";
private static final String SPACE_ID = "x";
private final CDAClient client = CDAClient
        .builder()
        .setToken(CDA_TOKEN)
        .setSpace(SPACE_ID)
        .build();

private List<Video> videos;

public Videos() {
    videos = new ArrayList<>();
    client
            .observe(CDAEntry.class)
            .where("content_type", "video")
            .all()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<CDAArray>() {
                CDAArray result;

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    for (final CDAResource resource : result.items()) {
                        CDAEntry entry = (CDAEntry) resource;
                        videos.add(new Video(entry.id(), entry.getField("videoTitle").toString(), entry.getField("videoDescription").toString(), R.drawable.dog));
                        Log.i("Contentful", entry.getField("videoTitle").toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Log.e("Contentful", "could not request entry", error);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(CDAArray cdaArray) {
                    result = cdaArray;
                }
            });
}

public List<Video> getVideos() {
    return videos;
}
}
```

VideoListAdapter.java

```
public class VideoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.VideoViewHolder> {

public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;
    TextView videoTitle;
    TextView videoDescription;
    ImageView videoPhoto;


    VideoViewHolder(View itemView, final VideoListViewActivity activity) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        videoTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        videoDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_description);
        videoPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_photo);

    }


}

Videos videos;
VideoListViewActivity videoListViewActivity;

VideoListAdapter(VideoListViewActivity videoListViewActivity, Videos videos) {
    this.videos = videos;
    this.videoListViewActivity = videoListViewActivity;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_card, viewGroup, false);
    VideoViewHolder videoViewHolder = new VideoViewHolder(v, videoListViewActivity);
    return videoViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder videoViewHolder, int i) {
    Video video = videos.getVideos().get(i);
    setOnClickListener(videoViewHolder.itemView, video);
    videoViewHolder.videoTitle.setText(videos.getVideos().get(i).videoTitle);
    videoViewHolder.videoDescription.setText(videos.getVideos().get(i).videoDescription);
    videoViewHolder.videoPhoto.setImageResource(videos.getVideos().get(i).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (videos.getVideos() == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return videos.getVideos().size();
    }
}

private void setOnClickListener(View itemView, final Video video) {
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VideoDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.VIDEO, video);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    CardView cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    TextView videoTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
    TextView videoDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_description);
    ImageView videoPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_photo);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    cardView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    videoTitle.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    videoDescription.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    videoPhoto.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
}
```

Comment: Actually no, your Log.* are not appearing, I suppose you are doing something wrong with your Rx initialization, but since I'm not familiar with it I can't tell for sure

Comment: Logging is far more helpful if you use your class as tag

Comment: I will update logs. thank you.

Comment: Also try to be more verbose and expressive, will allow you to find out what's wrong